# How to delete the folder with dropbox sdk on android?

Tags: android, dropbox

I want to delete the folder in dropbox with android by using dropbox sdk.

In this URL below, function's name is written. But I don't understand how to write a code.

https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.5-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#delete%28java.lang.String%29

If I put a file on dropbox, I can do like:

> Entry entry = mApi.putFile(path, is, length, null, null);

although when I delete a folder on dropbox and write a code below, it doesn't work.

> Entry entry = mApi.delete(path);

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

end the file path with a "/"

so for instance if the folder name is "MyPhotos", dropbox will return the path of "/MyPhotos", so just do a check and add a "/" to then file path:

```
if (e.isDir)
   mApi.delete(e.path +"/");
else
   mApi.delete(e.path);
```

this will delete the folder and it's contents.

Also delete(String path) is a void function so you wont be getting anything back so your

```
Entry entry = mApi.delete(path);
```

is not valid.

also you may want to wrap that in a try catch as it throws a DropboxException and run it on a background thread as it may take a while to delete the file.